# Support '#' in universal links iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

How to add '#' character into URL. I need to support universal link: [www.domain.com/#/my-app](http://www.domain.com/#/my-app)
I' ve tried: 
1."components": [{"#": "#", "/": "*/my-app"}]
2."components": [{"#": "*", "/": "*/my-app"}]
3."components": [{"#": "", "/": "*/my-app"}]

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": ["app id"],
             "components": [
               { 
                 "/": "/my-app", 
                 "#": "*" 
               }
             ]
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide swift code.

Comment: It's part of association file. I'll add a full file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it. May be it will help someone. Here is my association file:

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": ["appID"],
             "components": [
               { 
                 "/": "/*", 
                 "#": "*my-app*" 
               }
             ]
           }
       ]
   }
}
```